# mongoid 4 wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) for scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I trying to create the following scope:

```
scope :involving, -> (user) do
    where("conversations.sender_id =? OR conversations.recipient_id =?", user.id, user.id)
  end
```

but I get:

> wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid's `where` doesn't understand SQL snippets like `a = ? OR b = ?`, it only wants a single hash argument. Hence your "3 for 1" error.

You want to use `any_of` to build an `:$or` query:

```
any_of(
  { :sender_id    => user.id },
  { :recipient_id => user.id }
)
```

Beware that multiple `any_of`s are combined so this:

```
M.any_of(a, b).any_of(c, d)
```

is saying:

```
a OR b OR c OR d # any_of(a, b, c, d)
```

rather than

```
(a OR b) AND (c OR d)
```

as you might expect.

If you're expecting to every combine OR conditions then you might want to combine the `sender_id` and `recipient_id` into a single array field:

```
field :involved_ids, :type => Array
```

so that you could say:

```
where(:involved_ids => user.id)
```

and avoid the OR-problem. You'd still have separate `sender_id` and `recipient_id` fields of course, you'd just duplicate the data to better fit your queries. Denormalizing your data to suit your queries is quite common with MongoDB.